# How can I get a view from a Job Scheduled run times?

Tags: oracle, view, jobs

How can I get a view from the next run times of a Job?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [DBMS_SCHEDULER.EVALUATE_CALENDAR_STRING](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72366)

Example:

```
DECLARE
    next_run_date TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
        DBMS_SCHEDULER.EVALUATE_CALENDAR_STRING('FREQ=HOURLY;BYHOUR=06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23;BYMINUTE=0;BYSECOND=0;BYDAY=Mon', NULL, next_run_date, next_run_date);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( next_run_date );
    END LOOP;
END;


2018-04-30 06:00:00.000
2018-04-30 07:00:00.000
2018-04-30 08:00:00.000
2018-04-30 09:00:00.000
2018-04-30 10:00:00.000
2018-04-30 11:00:00.000
2018-04-30 12:00:00.000
2018-04-30 13:00:00.000
2018-04-30 14:00:00.000
2018-04-30 15:00:00.000
```

In case your are asking for [DBMS_JOB](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_job.htm#BABHCBFD) it is more difficult because unlike `SCHEDULER JOBS` the "next time" is evaluated **after** current job has been finished.

Comment: i can use it with some variables, Thanks

Comment: Of course, the calendar string may come as variable.